# the function "delete" affect console.log?

Tags: javascript

I saw a video about it, its example code is here. The result is "Before **delete obj.age** there are three attributes(**age name color**) in the obj, After *delete obj.age* there are two attributes(**name color**) in the obj" in the video. But when I try it **on my computer (macOS 10.15.7 Catalina  Chrome 97.0.4692.71)**, Whether before or after, the console.log results are same ---here are two attributes(*name color*) in the **obj**

```js
var obj = {};
obj.name = 'canoe';
obj.age = 1;
obj['color'] = 'blue';
console.log(obj.age);
//before delete age
console.log(obj);
delete obj.age;
//After delete age
console.log(obj);
```

The result in my computer is:

```js
1
{
  "name": "canoe",
  "color": "blue"
}
{
  "name": "canoe",
  "color": "blue"
}
```

Comment: it works in node.js and chrome too

Comment: you just delete the age attribute
before : {
  "name": "canoe",
  "age": 1,
  "color": "blue"
} After: {
  "name": "canoe",
  "color": "blue"
}

Comment: yes but in my computer : before delete age; "console.log" 's result is  {"color": "blue", "name": "canoe" } ;  after delete age; "console.log" 's result is {"color": "blue", "name": "canoe" };

Comment: Stop before deleting and expand the logged object. Then delete, log again and expand the result. See the second linked duplicate.

Comment: If you consider [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11568#issuecomment-283856965), a possible solution to have a sync `console.log` could be [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11568#issuecomment-348681867)

Comment: Thanks everybody. I know it now. Thanks!